# Why does archive.org say that it got HTTP 302 for this URL?

Tags: archive.org

I have an URL https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.FSPHYS/index.html which uses an HTTP 301 response to redirect to the URL https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.FSPHYS/. However, when I look at the [saved URL in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160606191116/https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.FSPHYS/index.html) ([archive.org](https://archive.org/web/)), I get this:

[image: archive.org claims that it got HTTP 302]

So archive.org claims that it got HTTP 302 as a response. As far as I can tell, this is not true (should be 301). Is this a bug in the Wayback Machine or am I missing something?

Comment: The Internet Archive tries to create an authentic record of Internet sites. If it received a particular response from a web site, it should record that properly. From that perspective, it’s all just data. Whether some site used a “temporary” or “permanent” redirect at some point in time may be interesting to someone, or it may be completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the Wayback Machine, inserted in 2010.

It's now fixed in the current Wayback Machine, and also our next-gen Wayback.